# how to modify the field value of a model when another field value of another model changes?

Tags: python, django

I have 4 models: reputation, goldbadge, sylverbadge and bronzebadge would like to add 1 in the bronzebadge model when the reputation model score reaches 100 score and this must be done automatically

here are my models

```
class reputation(models.Model):
    score=models.BigIntegerField(default=0)
    user=models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name="reputation_user")
    def __str__(self):
        return self.score

class goldBadge(models.Model):
    score=models.BigIntegerField(default=0)
    user=models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name="goldbadge_user")
    def __str__(self):
        return self.score
```

the other models are almost identical

My concern is that when saving the reputation model we will first check if the score is greater than or equal to 100 if yes then we increase the value of bronzebadge by 1

I am only a beginner in python and django so your help will do me a lot of good thank you for your answers already

Comment: increase 1 in silverbadge or bronzebadge...?? you have specified two different things in the question. Please update the question with correct one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a post signal which will check based on reputation model and will change the bronzebadge model.

A snippet of it can be found below:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=reputation)
def update_badge(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if instance.score > 100:
        user_bronze = bronzebadge.objects.filter(user=instance.user)[0]
        user_score = user_bronze.score + 1
        user_bronze.score = user_score
        user_bronze.save()
```

You can find the signal tutorial [here](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/28/how-to-create-django-signals.html).

Comment: thank you very much for your answer I wanted to up vote your answer but unfortunately I do not yet have the number of reputations requested to vote. your answer helped me a lot